# yasnippet insert the current date

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I tried to create a template which insert a transaction with the current date

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: breakfast
# key: breakfast
# condition: t                    
# --

2019-09-05 * ""
           Assets:DebtWechat  CNY
           Expenses:Food:Breakfast
```

How could change `2019-09-05` to a insert-current-date function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [embed elisp code](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#orgcde188c) in your snippet.  For your example, you could use something like

```
`(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")` * ""
```